# Linq-To-SQL attribute mapping string property containing DbGenerated primary key

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq-To-SQL with Attribute mapping, and have a class with the following properties:

```
private long item_Id;
[Column(Storage="item_Id", IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
public long Item_Id;

private string description;
[Column(Storage="description")]
public string Description
{ 
    get { return description; }
    set { description = value; }
} 

private string lookup_Id;
[Column(Storage="lookup_Id")]
public string Lookup_Id
{
    get { return lookup_Id.ToString() + "|" + Description; }
}
```

The Lookup_Id field actually contains significantly more data, but I've narrowed the scope for this question.

As it is, this setup allows me to use the database generated primary key as a portion of the object's Lookup_Id property.

My problem is that I need to import items into this database from a different source, and the Lookup_Id of those items needs to be set by a defined string; not generated by gathering values of other properties.

I can change my Lookup_Id property to one with a regular getter/setter and add an extension method that populated the Lookup_Id.  However, this would require me to save all my objects to the database first to get their database-generated primary key values assigned, then call the extension method to populate the Lookup_Id property, then save the items again.

Is there some way I can accomplish this without the need to save my objects twice?  I need to be able to generate the Lookup_Id with the primary key value populated for items my system creates, but I also need to be able to assign the Lookup_Id with values I might import from a CSV file, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a new class derived from the existing one? mark your Lookup_Id as virtual and override it in the new class... Would it help achieving your goal?

Comment: I suppose this would work, so I'm accepting as valid answer.  However, my solution was simply to add another property that would house the ID of imported items.  My Lookup_Id property is simply a string built from other properties of the object, so I made that property readonly, and check the imported ID field in the Lookup_Id getter.  If it's null, I use the object's primary key value; otherwise, I use the value in the imported ID field.